# Script to move files between folders on a Synology server

Tags: linux, nas, synology

On my Synology server I have a source folder `/volume1/Temp/a` and a destination folder `/volume1/Temp/b`.

I will like a script that I can schedule to run daily under DSM's control panel/task scheduler to move all files from the source folder to the destination folder. I did some searches and this is what I did so far but it does not work.

I created a file `/usr/local/bin/movefiles.sh` and gave it execute permissions.

I created a user define script under DSM task scheduler that runs this command: `/usr/local/bin/movefiles.sh >> /var/log/movefiles.log 2>&1`

The code in movefiles.sh:

```
$sSrc="/volume1/Temp/a"
$sDst="/volume1/Temp/b"

find $sSrc -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.*" -exec mv {} $sDst \;
```

The error I get is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/movefiles.sh: line 1: =/volume1/Temp/a
: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/movefiles.sh: line 2: =/volume1/Temp/b
: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/movefiles.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
mv: missing destination file operand after './SYNO.Core.SNMP.lib'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing destination file operand after './SYNO.Core.Security.DoS.lib'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing destination file operand after './SYNO.Backup.Service.NetworkBackup.lib'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing destination file operand after './SYNO.Core.Security.lib'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your variables without $, ie:

```
sSrc="/volume1/Temp/a"
sDst="/volume1/Temp/b"
```